# Class UsersController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-4

If I goto terminal and type: php artisan routes
I get an error.

```
c:\wamp\www\re3>php artisan routes
<?

class UsersController extends BaseController {
    protected $layout = 'layouts/main';

    public function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('getDashboard')));
    }

    public function getRegister() {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('users/register');
    }

    public function getLogin() {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('users/login');
    }

    public function getLogout() {
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', '<div class="alert a
lert-success">Your are now logged out!</div>');
    }

    public function getDashboard() {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('users/dashboard');
    }

    public function postCreate() {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $user = new User;
            $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
            $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();

            return Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', '<div class="ale
rt alert-success">Your account has been created. You may login now.</div>');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('users/register')->with('message', '<div class="
alert alert-danger">The following errors occurred</div>')->withErrors($validator
)->withInput();
        }
    }

    public function postSignin() {
        if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input:
:get('password')))) {
        return Redirect::to('users/dashboard')->with('message', '<div class="ale
rt alert-success">You are now logged in!</div>');
    } else {
            return Redirect::to('users/login')
            ->with('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger">Your username/pas
sword combination was incorrect.</div>')
            ->withInput();
        }
    }
}
{"error":{"type":"ReflectionException","message":"Class UsersController does not
 exist","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\re3\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\
\Routing\\ControllerInspector.php","line":28}}line":28}}
```

And now I'm trying to add an index() method to my ListingsController.php but I also keep getting controller does not exist even though I have the controllers and the views and the models.

My Routes

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
Route::controller('listings', 'ListingsController');
Route::get('add', array('uses' => 'ListingsController@getAdd'));
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you do a `composer dumpautoload -o`?

Comment: Lets start at the beginning is the UsersController in /app/contollers/UsersController.php

Comment: No I didn't do dumpautoload, should I?

Comment: I just did the dumpautoload and I got a new error
Generating optimized autoload file

  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "app/tests/TestCase.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

dump-autoload [-o|--optimize] [--no-dev]

Comment: But without listings, does the `UsersController` works fine?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I am able to register/login and even associate the user_id in the listings table. It all works.

Comment: Sounds like you've moved some stuff around (based on the fact that you've deleted the tests folder, which is causing the autoload error).  Go in to your composer.json file in the root directory and delete the "autoload" entry relating to the ``app/tests`` folder.  Then run `composer dump-autoload` again.